# Is there a public database for enthalpy of solution values?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm looking for a public database for enthalpy of solution values. The CRC handbook only has selected compounds available. The NIST webbook doesn't appear to have any enthalpy of solution values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Here](https://www.crct.polymtl.ca/thermo_databases.html)?

Comment: It's not that easy. I found that same site through a quick google search, but the sites linked on that page are all subscription based, not public.

Comment: Your question still is a bit broad.  If possible, set a focus on the specific compound / compound class and the solvent intended.  Is it about dissolving salts in water, or organic compounds in each other?